# update always inserting last array value

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

i m new to node and search a lot find solution but don't know how to use with my condition if anyone pro who can help me with this thing

```
Permissiontb.assembleAndInsert = async (ctx, cb) => {
for (let i = 0; i < ctx.req.body.view.length; i++) {
       console.log('outside i  '+i)
       await Process(ctx,i);
 }
};

 function  Process(ctx,i) {
let data={company_id:ctx.args.options.accessToken.userId,
       userid:ctx.req.body.userid,
       perpage:ctx.req.body.perpage[i].id,
       view:ctx.req.body.view[i],
       edit:ctx.req.body.edit[i],
       update:ctx.req.body.update[i],
       delete:ctx.req.body.delete[i]}

     console.log('inside '+i)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Permissiontb.find({where:{and: [{userid:ctx.req.body.userid}, {perpage:ctx.req.body.perpage[i].id}] }},function(err,result){
     if(err){
             var err = new Error('Some thing went wrong');
             err.statusCode = 444;
             console.log('err'+err)
             resolve(err)
     }else{ console.log(result.length)
         if(result.length>0){
           console.log(ctx.req.body.userid)  
           console.log('page id '+ctx.req.body.perpage[i].id)
           const pgid=ctx.req.body.perpage[i].id
           const vd=ctx.req.body.view[i]
           const ed=ctx.req.body.edit[i]
           const up=ctx.req.body.update[i]
           const del=ctx.req.body.delete[i]
            console.log(ctx.req.body.view[i])
            console.log(ctx.req.body.edit[i])
            console.log(ctx.req.body.update[i])
            console.log(ctx.req.body.delete[i])
            console.log('findinside update '+i)

              resolve(Permissiontb.update({where:{and: [{userid:ctx.req.body.userid}, {perpage:pgid}] }},{view:vd,edit:ed,update:up,delete:del}))

         }else{
             resolve(Permissiontb.create([data]))
         }

     }

    })

 })
}
```

now problem is that  console log inside if(result.lenght>0) condition for eg:- console.log(ctx.req.body.view[i]) correct value getting but when  update method always inserting last array value can anyone tell me what i m doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found soultion may be this will help other who facing issue like me

```
var async = require('async');
 module.exports = function(Permissiontb) {
Permissiontb.assembleAndInsert = async (ctx, cb) => {

for (let i = 0; i < ctx.req.body.view.length; i++) {
       await Process(ctx,i);
   }
 };
Permissiontb.remoteMethod('assembleAndInsert', {
    http: {
      path: '/assembleAndInsert',
      verb: 'post',
     },
accepts: [{ arg: 'data', type: 'object', http: { source: 'context' } },

{"arg": "options", "type": "object", "http": "optionsFromRequest"}],
returns: {
  arg: 'data',
  type: 'object',
},
});


function  Process(ctx,i) {
  let data={company_id:ctx.args.options.accessToken.userId,
            userid:ctx.req.body.userid,
            perpage:ctx.req.body.perpage[i].id,
            view:ctx.req.body.view[i],
             edit:ctx.req.body.edit[i],
             update:ctx.req.body.update[i],
            delete:ctx.req.body.delete[i]}
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 resolve(Permissiontb.upsertWithWhere({userid:ctx.req.body.userid,perpage:ctx.req.body.perpage[i].id},data))

  })
 }
```

problem is that i m using Permissiontb.upsertWithWhere(//im using where here->{userid:ctx.req.body.userid,perpage:ctx.req.body.perpage[i].id},data))